# Fast Graphics with XServer

Tags: python, linux

I am working on **embedded linux platform with limited system resources**.

**I want to do fullscreen slideshow with simple transistions (like slide in-out, fade in-out )**.

I tried PyGtk+GTK+Cairo but its very slow, when I animate GTK image controls I get just two or three frames per second. But smplayer is playing video at good speed!

I did some little research and came to know about [directfb](http://www.directfb.org/), [libggi](http://www.ggi-project.org/), [svgalib](http://www.svgalib.org/) etc. and I don't know what library should be used.

Which library is the best for this kind of application? I would prefer to do this without stopping X.

Comment: You might want to specify what those limited system resources are, because today's embedded systems are high-powered computers compared to the desktops of 10-15 years ago.

Comment: I am using SmartQ7  Samsung ARM S3C6410 @ 667MHz, 128MB RAM, 1GB flash, Eventhough its processor have hardware accelerator , drivers are not yet available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try this first using just PyCairo, not using GTK controls at all.

However, if that does not give you the speed that you need, then you might want to try PyGame which gives you access to SDL including OpenGL backends. PyGame is very actively developed and used in building applications that include full screen animation so even if you are not writing a game, you will still likely find the best support by using PyGame.

Comment: I tried PyGame its faster, but not upto my expectation, i will live with it as of now. thanks, Michael.